# Fraudulent hoax

Tags: banking

A friend deposited $300 to my bank account after I needed help with a bill ( we always help each other out back and forth). After rejecting him for a date he claimed he wanted his money back, which I had no problem with, but he then said be put out a fraudulent on my card. This makes no sense since she willingly made the bank transaction, I didn't force him to send money to my account. Will I be facing fraud charges? Is it even possible in the stupid scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Every legitimate claim I've filed regarding fraudulent charges on my card includes signing a legal document. If your "friend" completes such a document and you can verify that it is untrue, he's in deeper trouble than you.

Unfortunately, if he's successful in filing a claim that is later proven to be fraudulent, it puts your account in a poor status until it's fully cleared. Even then, corporate inertia may result in longer duration inaccurate information.

Once you've cleared the fraudulent claim, you'll want to contact your credit agency to ensure they are provided with correct and proper documentation.